# Posting on facebook page

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm posting on a page on Facebook, using the following code.

```
def _PostToFB(message):
    token = getattr(settings, 'FACEBOOK_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN', "")
    page  = str(getattr(settings, 'FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID', 123))

    user_account = OpenFacebook(token)
    accounts = user_account.get('me/accounts')
    for x in accounts['data']:
        if x['id'] == page:
            page = x
            break
    else:
        # page not found
        print "Page not found with corresponding ID"
        return

    page_graph = OpenFacebook(page['access_token'])
    result = page_graph.set('me/feed', message=message)

    print "FB post result:", result
```

This adds a post on facebook, and it shows that the [post is public](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heVx0.jpg). And so I never really checked it for around a couple of months. However, on getting complaints, and on checking it, I found that **no one, except me** is able to view the posts, even though they are clearly public. Others simply do not see the post.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely your app is still in development mode. Check top of Status&Review tab in app dashboard, and set it “live”.

Comment: It is indeed in development mode. It seems stupid I didn't think of that. Let me see if this resolves the issue.

Comment: @CBroe : that fixed it. Would you write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app was still in development mode. Anything posted by an app in development mode is only visible to people that have a role in the app (admin/developer/tester), but stays hidden from the general public.

Setting it “live” is done on top of Status&Review tab in app dashboard.